# Django admin models

Tags: django, forms, django-admin

I have these models :

```
class Filters(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return format('%s' % self.title)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Name filter')


class FilterValue(models.Model):

    value = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='value filter')
    filter = models.ForeignKey(Filters)


class Casino(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Name Casino')
    filters = models.ManyToManyField(Filters)
```

In admin

```
class AdminCasino(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields= ['title','filters']
```

How can I get view in admin multiselect:

- Name Filter
- --value filter of this name

and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am completely understanding your question but it sounds like you want tabular inlines.

Try adding the following to your admin

```
class FilterValueInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FilterValue

class AdminCasino(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FilterValueInline]
```